# Cosmic rays characteristics/parameters

Tags: cosmic-ray

Where can I get the numerical information about cosmic rays? This is what I need:

- Cosmic rays composition: As I found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_ray#Composition) 99% bare nuclei and 1% electrons. out of 99% bare nuclei: 90% protons, 9% alpha particles, 1% other nuclei of heavier elements. I recaculated it like this:

  - 89.1% - protons
  - 8.91% - alpha particles
  - 1% - electrons
  - 0.99% - nuclei of heavier elements
- Average energy of the cosmic ray. There is a graph [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_ray#/media/File:Cosmic_ray_flux_versus_particle_energy.svg) but I do not understand what is on the Y axis. It is written $F\ (m2\ sr\ s\ GeV)^{-1}$. Can someone explain what does it means?
- Energy flux per square meter per second ($Watt/m^2$). Also, as I understand the graph above is only about energy distribution of the cosmic rays, not about how much energy or particles per square meter per second is coming.
- Cosmic rays flux distribution in the Earth atmosphere? Like if altitude is 1000 km it is $10^{-5}Watt/m^2$, if altitude is 100 km it is $XWatt/m^2$, etc.

If anyone knows where to get this information with the source references it will help a lot.

Comment: No gamma ray component?

Comment: It will be good to know all of them. For example, if average flux is $1\ W/m^2$ and 50% of this flux is gamma rays and other 50% protons, nuclei and electrons then it will be useful.